# Real time integration guidance

Tags: integration

I am trying to learn integration in SFDC and I am looking for step by step guide for integration.

Please guide me.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: There are a lot of different types of SF integrations. Could you pls give us more information about what do you try to do? Start searching for Sreaming API if you need realtime: http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Getting_Started_with_the_Force.com_Streaming_API

Comment: thanks. I am looking for basic integration where I can do it so that I can get confidence in integration and then I would like to move to advacned integration like SOAP and RESP API's

Comment: @ArunSFDC The basic integrations are REST, SOAP, and Email. Which type of integration do you want? Also, do you want inbound (to Salesforce), outbound (from Salesforce), or both? Before you can design an integration, you have to know what the goal of the integration is. We understand that this is a learning exercise, but each exercise must have a goal. Without a definition of the exercise, you cannot even begin an integration.

Comment: The integration overview at Developer.force.com is a good start. Best video overview video IMHO can be found at  pluralsght.com "patterns in cloud integration" by Richard Seroter

Comment: Thanks SFDCFox, Yes I would like to learn both Inbound and Outbound integration. I am looking for good post where someone made integration step by step.

Answer (score 1):

Salesforce provides an Integration workbook which goes through integrating a Heroku app with a Salesforce instance. That can be found [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/integration_workbook/integration_workbook.pdf).